# snowsight page is displayed too slowly when the many queries is thrown

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using a snowflake trial version to do a performance test.

I perform 9 heavy queries (20 mins taken by XS cluster) at the same time and watch the warehouse or history pane. However, the time to display page is too much; about 30 seconds.

I think the cloudservice (like hadoop headnode?) doesn't have adequate resources to do this.
Is it because I'm using the trial version? If I use enterprise or business critical versions, will it happen?

Comment: Are all these being run from multiple sessions of Snowsight or from a single worksheet? Also, what is the browser and version from which the test is being run?

Comment: These queries are run by each worksheets. so that we use 9 worksheets. Browser is Google Chrome (latest version) and a proxy server isn't via.

Comment: And one of these queries' profile can't see by the internal error nonetheless the status is successed. Although I did by the secret browser or the other browser, its error continues.

Answer (score 0):

The "cloud services", is actually unrelated to your warehouses, and 9 queries is not enough overload that. But at the same time the trial accounts might be on slightly underpowered SC layer, but I am not sure why that would be the case. The allocated credit spend is just that.

I am puzzled what you are trying to "test" about running many slow for the server sized queries at the same time?

When you say the page takes 30 seconds to load, do you mean if you do nothing the query execution status/time is only updated every ~30 seconds, or if you do a full page reload it is blank for 30 seconds?

Comment: What is the "SC layer"?
I tested whether the many sized queries make the webpage perfromance down or not because I confirm that there are no problem when many enduser use the same snowflake account at the sametime. If the performance go down, the system is not good for my usecase.

Comment: When I click the warehosue or the history pain,as these queries run, the page is blank for 30 seconds. If the queries are finished, the problem has gone.